# How to get Angular2 dart to work in IE11

Tags: angular, dart, internet-explorer-11

I had problems with my app and IE11, so I just cloned the [toh-6](https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-6) project and tried to run it in IE11 and got the same error:

```
RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0
at ioore (http://10.0.2.2:8080/main.dart.js:3843:7)
at BrowserDomAdapter.getBaseHref$0 (http://10.0.2.2:8080/main.dart.js:29341:11)
at BrowserPlatformLocation.getBaseHrefFromDOM$0 (http://10.0.2.2:8080/main.dart.js:29423:9)
at PathLocationStrategy.PathLocationStrategy$2 (http://10.0.2.2:8080/main.dart.js:29716:11)
at PathLocationStrategy.static.PathLocationStrategy$ (http://10.0.2.2:8080/main.dart.js:29724:11)
...
```

I have tried with angular2 `2.0.0` and `2.2.0`, both produce the same error.

I have found a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2/issues/94) from September that seems to be the same problem.

I think that Google is already using angular2 dart in their projects (I assume that they also support IE11), so there must be a workaround for this problem.

**EDIT**: as user `@dergemkr` on GitHub pointed out: the problem exists only if `<base href="/">` is set to `/`, that's why the examples (which are set to `<base href="/toh-6">` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently a fix is on it's way. In the meantime, this is how you get it to work:

In [`angular2/lib/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.dart#510`](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2/blob/655d2b49000fee008d834cdb0ff2dfed8bbca2b4/lib/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.dart#L510) change this line:

```
  return (pathname[0] == '/') ? pathname : '/${pathname}';
```

to this:

```
return (pathname.isEmpty || pathname[0] == '/') ? pathname : '/${pathname}';
```